# FreeBSD User Space DTrace and dumping function arguments for user space

Tags: freebsd, dtrace

Can we dump function arguments for user space functions just like for functions 
in kernel space? Can FBT provider dump arguments for user space functions if we 
do dtrace -l -f  -v?

I was DTrace'ing "top" utility, (the "top" utility has both 
the CTF and the Dwarf debug sections built in the object file)

I am trying to inspect get_system_info function called by "top", I 
confirm it is present to be probed

```
root% dtrace -l | grep get_system_info 
55154  pid8488      top        get_system_info entry
```

But I cannot dump the arguments to the function...

```
root% dtrace -l -f get_system_info -v 
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME 
55154    pid8488               top                   get_system_info entry 

        Probe Description Attributes 
                Identifier Names: Private 
                Data Semantics:   Private 
                Dependency Class: Unknown 

        Argument Attributes 
                Identifier Names: Private 
                Data Semantics:   Private 
                Dependency Class: Unknown 

        Argument Types 
                None
```

Testing with a simple script,

```
pid8488::get_system_info:entry
{ 
    this->info = (struct system_info *)copyin(args[0], sizeof(struct system_info)); 
}
```

...if I use the args[0] notation it says the following,

```
dtrace: failed to compile script top_d.d: line 17: index 0 is out of 
range for pid8488::get_system_info:entry args[ ]
```

Instead if I replace with arg0, it compiles but the values are not 
neccesarily sane. 
Example the ncpus member of struct system_info shows a garbage value.

The complete script is

```
pid8488::get_system_info:entry
{
    this->info = (struct system_info *)copyin(arg0, sizeof(struct system_info));
    printf("last pid [%d] \n", this->info->last_pid);
}
pid8488::get_process_info:entry
{
    this->info = (struct system_info *)copyin(arg0, sizeof(struct system_info)); 
    printf("ncpus [%d] \n", this->info->ncpus); 
}
```

Running this

```
55154         get_system_info:entry last pid [8513] 
55155         get_process_info:entry ncpus [134558720]
```

Supposed to be showing number of cpus? Anything wrong with the scripting?

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at investigating this on 9.1 and 9.2-RC2 but I couldn't get DTrace working properly on either so my comments are based on the Solaris version, which should be broadly equivalent.

The fbt provider instruments kernel functions.  Its user-land equivalent is the pid provider.

The pid provider certainly can expose function arguments but, unless FreeBSD's DTrace supports user-land CTF, their types will not be available.  This is probably why you've found that the typed `args[n]` are not available and you are restricted instead to the integer `argn`.

I'm guessing that the function `get_system_info()` populates the `struct system_info`.  If that's the case then you must copy in the structure *after* you return from the function.
In addition, if dtrace(1) can't find that structure's definition then you'll have to provide it yourself, by including either it or an appropriate header file (and using the `-C` flag).
Here's an (untested) example:

```
struct system_info {
    ...
    unsigned int ncpus;
    ...
};

pid$target::get_system_info:entry
{
    self->siup = (uintptr_t)arg0;       /* user-land pointer */
}

pid$target::get_system_info:return
/self->siup/
{
    this->sikp = (struct system_info *) /* kernel pointer */
        copyin(self->siup, sizeof (struct system_info));
    printf("ncpus = %d\n", this->sikp->ncpus);
    self->siup = 0;             /* free thread-local storage */
}
```

Finally, when evaluating data types (e.g. pointer sizes), dtrace(1) will
default to the data model of the running kernel.  If you're running a 64-bit kernel but you're instrumenting a 32-bit process then use the "`-32`" flag so that dtrace(1) uses the appropriate sizes for the various types it sees.